# Angular-UI Bootstrap : pass value from Trigger's button to Modal's button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Need some guidance. I am using angular-ui-bootstrap with php and mysql. I want to pass value from list of link (generated from php mysql) to modal button each time modal loads.

HTML

```
// Below link is while-loop with php-mysql result
<a href="#" data-refno="<?php echo $r->wo_ref_no; ?>" ng-click="open()">Issue</a> 

<script type="text/ng-template" id="SubmissionReminder.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Submission Work Order Request</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Please ensure quotation(s) or any document(s) related to this Work Order is ready for Procurement Unit to proceed accordingly.
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <a href="issue.php?wo_ref={{ refno }}" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
  </div>
</script>
```

JS

```
app.controller('userWOController', function ($scope, $modal) {

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function () {
    $scope.items = [];
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl : 'SubmissionReminder.html',
      controller: 'SubmissionReminder'
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});


app.controller('SubmissionReminder', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

I'm stuck on how to pass value from trigger (a href) to modal button (a href).

Comment: Does the userWOController see's the value you want to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send data into modal controller pass through `resolve` object:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
  templateUrl : 'SubmissionReminder.html',
  controller: 'SubmissionReminder',
  resolve: {
    refno: function () {
      return {refno: $scope.refno};
    }
  }
});
```

Then get resolved `refno` from modal controller:

```
app.controller('SubmissionReminder', function ($scope, $modalInstance, refno) {
  $scope.refno = refno().refno;
  ...
}
```

Comment: `app.controller('SubmissionReminder', function ($scope, $modalInstance, refno) {
 $scope.refnos = refno;

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});` @vmaksym .. was it like this? Then just add {{ refno }} add Modal's buttton?

Comment: I've edited SubmissionReminder controller to show how to call it. Yes than you can add it to button like you show me.